# C# simple directX control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, directx

I would like to implement basic 3D visualization in my winforms app using DirectX

My model:

- polygons with holes and thickness
- cylinders
- text 2D
- textures basic
- lighting

Scene control:

- zoom
- panning
- rotate

Is any "all in one" .net control that I can easy put on form and setup my model by adding shape primitives ?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but it's a very interesting question. If it does exist, I'd be interested to know more.

Comment: This might get you part of the way there:  http://sites.google.com/site/quamtar/d3dcontrols-main  I've never used it but the screen-shots look promising

Comment: But note that quamtar's control is using Managed DirectX which was discontinued in favor of XNA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've implemented Awesomium WebControl with html page using three.js library. This is allows me easily show 3d models (and dynamically generate model) using GPU acceleration (WebGL backend).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a control that has the exact functionality you want, but [this sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1) contains a `GraphicsDeviceControl` which I've used in the past to obtain a similar control as the one you want. You'll have to add zoom, panning, rotate but this shouldn't be too difficult in 3D world.